# React hooks onHover modal on each array item

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

The modal(green box) needs to appear under each seperate red box once there is an onHover event. at the moment the green box is only appearing in the same area. so it would be a modal opening under each different red box. thanks in advance

sandbox here https://codesandbox.io/s/modal-array-ccpso3?file=/src/App.js:0-1283

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import roundFace from "../src/sad.png";

const data = [
  { image: roundFace, number: 1 },
  { image: roundFace, number: 2 },
  { image: roundFace, number: 3 }
];

export const Items = (imageUrl, heading) => (
  <div className="flex flex-col">
    <div className="px-2 py-2 mx-auto align-middle">
      <div className="w-16 h-16 border-solid border-4 border-red-600">
        <img className="" src={imageUrl} alt="" />
        <div className={heading} />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
);
export const App = () => {
  const [Hover, setHover] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div className="">
      <div className="grid gap-x-8 gap-y-4 grid-cols-3 px-2 py-2">
        {data &&
          data.length > 0 &&
          data.map((box, index) => (
            <div key={`-${index}`}>
              <div
                onMouseEnter={() => setHover(true)}
                onMouseLeave={() => setHover(false)}
              >
                <Items imageUrl={box.image} />
              </div>
              {box.number}
            </div>
          ))}
        {Hover && (
          <p className="w-16 h-16 border-solid border-4 border-green-600">
            Hi!
          </p>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;

import * as React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

import App from "./App";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: The code in your sandbox doesn't match your snippet here. It also seems to do what you want already. The question/issue is unclear.

Comment: Hi, the sandbox should be fixed now with the original problem, it rally just needs the same modal (green square) to open under the red squares on hover irrespective of the number on it. the numbers are just on there do demonstrate that they are different from each other

Comment: Do you mean positionally? Or something else? Right now I see a green square under each red square when the red is hovered.

Comment: My bad, there is a correct link now in the description https://codesandbox.io/s/modal-array-ccpso3?file=/src/App.js:0-1283

Comment: Sorry if I'm just misunderstanding what you are asking for. The sandbox code matches your snippet here, but now I see only one green box to the left under the red boxes. What is the issue? What are you expecting?

Comment: oh, the green box to appear seperate under each red box when the onHover event, A similar example  if the red boxes were all different buttons an the green boxes was a modal/dropdown opening under the red box

Comment: Isn't that what you had the first time with other sandbox code? That code looked like the code in MC Naveen's answer. Is that not what you are describing the expected result to be?

Comment: Correct its the desired result, the only issue is that the code is dependant on the numbers in the array, is there any way to accomplish this without relying on the 1,2,3 in the object? it could rely on the index instead

Comment: Are you referring specifically to the `number` property in the `data` array elements? You could call it `id` instead, since this is what it seems you are using it for. Does that make sense? Other than this, you could use the mapped array index, but this is prone to issue if you are mutating the array (*adding, removing, sorting, etc...*).

Comment: Yeah it does make sense, thanks so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified the `App.js` and Here it is.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import roundFace from "../src/sad.png";

const data = [
  { image: roundFace, number: 0 },
  { image: roundFace, number: 1 },
  { image: roundFace, number: 2 }
];

export const Items = (imageUrl, heading) => (
  <div className="flex flex-col">
    <div className="px-2 py-2 mx-auto align-middle">
      <div className="w-16 h-16 border-solid border-4 border-red-600">
        <img className="" src={imageUrl} alt="" />
        <div className={heading} />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
);
export const App = () => {
  const [Hover, setHover] = useState(null);

  return (
    <div className="">
      <div className="grid gap-x-8 gap-y-4 grid-cols-3 px-2 py-2">
        {data &&
          data.length > 0 &&
          data.map((box, index) => (
            <div key={`attendees-${index}`}>
              <div
                onMouseEnter={() => setHover(index)}
                onMouseLeave={() => setHover(false)}
              >
                <Items imageUrl={box.image} />
              </div>
              {box.number}
              <span>{Hover === box.number ? <p className="w-16 h-16 border-solid border-4 border-green-600">Wow</p> : ""}</span>

              {/* {Hover && (
              )} */}
            </div>
          ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

I'm hovering on the 2nd Box and the Modal is appearing.

Is this what you're looking for?

[image]

Things I have changed:

- Number value in the data array
- UseState to null

Why did I change it?

The array starts from 0 so, I'm checking the `box.number` is equal to the Index number(Which is present in Hover). If yes, the box will appear.

Comment: Totally what Im looking for, awesome .

Comment: Great. Glad it helps